# Sublime SFTP plugin : ignore-regex for certain folder names

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Using the `ignore-regex` settings of Sublime SFTP plugin, which is set by default to :

```
"\\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\\d?)?\\\.json", 
"sftp-settings\\\.json", "/venv/", "\\\.svn/", "\\\.hg/", "\\\.git/", 
"\\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\\.db", "desktop\\\.ini"
```

How can I ignore folders with specific types of names, for example all folder which name is a digit ? Example: /54/ , /108/ etc.

Comment: So you want a regex matching all digits?

Comment: yes, but which takes into account the way it's implemented here, with the backslash thing I don't fully understand by the way

Comment: I suspect it's escaping the characters for some sort of pre-parsing.

Comment: Ah - it's because it's represented as JSON, then parsed as a regex, http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings#setting-ignore_regexes

Answer (score 0):

This should do it -- RegEx and JSON require that backslashes be escaped, so we have to escape the backslash before the digits twice.

```
\\\d+
```

Comment: I tried so like : , `"/\\\d+/"` but I get : `Error parsing sftp-config.json file:
Invalid \escape: line 27 column 13 (char 841)`. With four backslash, I have no error, but it doesn't work